# images not showing in my slider in React, styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Added: I am not getting any errors on console...
Functionally, I am not yet to implement anything besides just the image and the layout themselves.

I am trying to implement my own slider in React.
I've checked images are all working fine themselves. The problem seems to be rather coming from the components.

Below is my base component, slider.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import SliderContent from './SliderContent';
import Slide from './Slide';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
`;

const Slider = ({ slides }) => {
    const getWidth = () => window.innerWidth;

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        translate: 0,
        transition: 0.45,
    });

    const { translate, transition } = state;
    const { setTranslate, setTransition } = setState;

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <SliderContent
                translate={translate}
                translation={transition}
                width={getWidth() * slides.length}
            >
                {slides.map((slide, i) => (
                    <Slide key={slide + i} content={slide} />
                ))}
            </SliderContent>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

export default Slider;
```

Below is where it determines the size for the slider.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    transform: translateX(-${(props) => props.translate}px);
    transition: transform ease-out ${(props) => props.transition}s;
    height: 100%;
    width: ${(props) => props.width}px;
    display: flex;
`;

const SliderContent = () => {
    return <Wrapper>Test</Wrapper>;
};

export default SliderContent;
```

This is the actual component that has the image.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    height: 100;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('${(props) => props.content}');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
`;

const Slide = ({ content }) => {
    console.log(content);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {content}
            <div>dfsfsdf</div>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

export default Slide;
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide either a functional example, or significantly more information about what the image "not showing" means. Are you seeing any errors? If you inspect the output is the Element/CSS there? What's being passed into the `Slider` component in the `slides` property?

Comment: on your component holding the image, you have ```height: 100``` without specifying ```px``` or something else, maybe it's because of that?

Comment: Fixed, not working.